# Remove the Floating of headers in NSTableview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a NSTableview in my application. Theres a header and under these are some elements like rows of a table view. So when i scroll this table view the header stays put and it scrolls up only if the last element in the table view scrolls up and disappers. I Need the header to scroll like the remaining rows. Please help. Is it possible.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck `Floats Group Rows`in Attribute Inspector of the Table View

Comment: Thanx vadian :) Exactly what i was looking for :) Thnq :)